# Assigning Table ID as a value to a variable in BigQuery

Tags: sql, variables, google-bigquery

I am trying to set a variable's value as a table's name. This is the query I am using.

```
DECLARE var STRING;


SELECT var = (SELECT

              ARRAY_AGG(table_id)[OFFSET(0)]

              FROM `dx-api-project.dv360_integration.__TABLES__`);

SELECT var
```

The query runs all fine, without any error. But when I see var's value, it shows null. However, when I just execute the query without variable declaration and assignment, ARRAY_AGG(table_id)[OFFSET(0)]'s value comes out to be what it should be.

Can anyone help me understand the issue here? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **SET** instead of **SELECT**. Valid syntax for setting a variable is :

```sql
DECLARE var STRING;
SET var = (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(table_id)[OFFSET(0)]
             FROM `dx-api-project.dv360_integration.__TABLES__`);
```

or initialize a variable with a default value,

```sql
DECLARE var STRING DEFAULT (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(table_id)[OFFSET(0)]
    FROM `dx-api-project.dv360_integration.__TABLES__`
);
```

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#set

Comment: Thanks @Jaytiger. I used SET instead of SELECT and its working fine now : )